# How do I change the directory where CVS in Eclipse asks me to create the known_hosts for SSH2?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, cvs

It keeps asking me to create the known_hosts file inside a network location I don't have access to. I need to change it to my computer's home directory (or somewhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set that in `Preferences>General>Network Connections>SSH2`

[image: SSH2 directory and preferences]